# Concrete5 to WordPress Redirect Issues

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, concrete5

We have created a Blog using WordPress which sits in a subfolder of a Concrete5 website. We used to have a blog through Concrete5 but decided to change. We have done the following redirect in the HTAccess file but it doesn't do what we want. An example is: -

```
Redirect 301 /latest-news/holograms-home/ http://www.comparemymove.com/blog/residential/holograms-in-the-home/
```

However, rather than redirecting to our desired page it goes to: -

```
http://www.comparemymove.com/blog/holograms-in-the-home/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show how does response to HTTP GET request to `http://www.comparemymove.com/latest-news/holograms-home/` looks like? (mainly headers)

Comment: Also I would say that your redirect works just fine, but it's later rewritten again. That means `/latest-news/holograms-home/` is rewritten to `/blog/residential/holograms-in-the-home/`, which in turn is rewritten to `/blog/holograms-in-the-home/`.